# Calculate cumulative rate with reset SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a excel workbook that has the formula I require but I now need to do the same in sql.

I have three columns; Analysis, loss, rate.

In excel I have two additional columns; Rank - sequential numbers starting a 1 for every analysis. 
Cumulative rate - running total sum of the rate, resetting when the rank = 1

Can someone please explain how this can be done in sql server?

Many thanks in advance and sorry if this question has been asked before, I was struggling to follow the answers to similar questions.

Alex

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the cumulative sum using a window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.rate) over (partition by t.analysis order by t.rank) as cumulative_rate
from t;
```

It is unclear from your question how `rank` is calculated.  In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, you need a column that specifies the ordering for operation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. To clarify, Rank is a sequential number denoting the order for each analysis. In the table there are lots of different analysis stacked. I want to calculate the cumulative rate for each, resetting after each analysis.

Comment: @AlexanderAlabaster . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, How would I create the column rank. In excel I have dine =IF(A2=A1,D1+1,1) where A is analysis and d is rank. I want to create a sequential column that restarts for every analysis

Comment: @AlexanderAlabaster . . . You need a column that specifies an ordering or an identity column when you insert the data into the database.